# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Tags: string, python-3.x, attributeerror

Having trouble on my code.
I am getting this AttributeError and i don't know why.
Someone provide a little insight please and thanks!!!
This is written in python 3, 
i am attempting to make a chart.

```
import sys
data = {}
def main():
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    parseFile(filename)
    function()    
def parseFile(fn):
    print("Parsing", fn)
    infile = open(fn, "r")
    for line in infile:
        line = line[:-1]
        tokens = line.split()
        print(tokens)
        if line[0]=="#":
            line.readline() #<-- this is my problem line
        rsid = (tokens[0])
        genotype = (tokens[3])
        data[rsid] = genotype
    infile.close()
main()

# This data file generated by 23andMe at: Wed Jan 26 05:37:08 2011
#
# Below is a text version of your data. Fields are TAB-separated
# Each line corresponds to a single SNP.  For each SNP, we provide its identifier 
# (an rsid or an internal id), its location on the reference human genome, and the 
# genotype call oriented with respect to the plus strand on the human reference 
# sequence.     We are using reference human assembly build 36.  Note that it is possible 
# that data downloaded at different times may be different due to ongoing improvements 
# in our ability to call genotypes. More information about these changes can be found at:
# https://www.23andme.com/you/download/revisions/
# 
# More information on reference human assembly build 36:
# http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/mapview/map_search.cgi?taxid=9606&build=36
#
# rsid  chromosome  position    genotype
rs4477212   1   72017   AA
rs3094315   1   742429  AA
rs1799883   1   742429  AA
rs3131972   1   742584  GG
rs12124819  1   766409  AA
rs11240777  1   788822  GG
rs6681049   1   789870  CC
rs4970383   1   828418  CC
rs4475691   1   836671  CC
rs7537756   1   844113  AA
```

Comment: That's what language? What's the exact error in which line? Have you tried to reduce your example?

Comment: ahhh. i'm sorry. python. error is in line.readline()
i have tried to reduce my example, but not the best at doing so

Comment: why do you have line.readline() there? what is your intent?

Comment: i'm trying this too

        print(tokens)
        line = line.readline()[1:]
        rsid = (tokens[0])

but to no avail

Comment: can you give an example of some of your lines in the file you are reading?

Comment: okay yeah i just added it above. sorry. trying to read in the first and third indexes into a dictionary. trying to skip over the # lines

Comment: @javadba dude, this was 3+ years ago and the py3 tag was added after. there was not much info in the question so I thought I'd get him to add some stuff.  just trying to be helpful.  you, are you being helpful right now?

Comment: @user1269942 Actually yes I was  - and glad to hear *you* were as well.  fyi: your first comment reads as a troll : the code is obviously python so why ask that - unless you meant "is it python2 or python3" .   I'll delete my comment - the point was actually to try to "protect" a bit a noobie (the OP) - who tend to get bashed around.

Comment: @javadba I suppose now I would dig up that sterile link that newbies get given about "how to post". At the time, I was new and I traded pleasantries in favour of giving rapid help.  Better wording would definitely withstand the test of time though.  It was clearly python, but not mentioned in text or title...next time: "please include the language in title and question text and tag" and I'll come across as more civilized...even though I'm not! I know, I'm breaking the rules again by chatting. Ahh...can't win! All the best.

Answer (score -1):

the attribute error means that readline is not a string method.

in this snippet:

```
for line in infile:
    line = line[:-1]
    tokens = line.split()
```

I am guessing (correctly?) that line[:-1] is to strip off a line feed. If that is the case, try this instead:

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    tokens = line.split()
```

strip will strip off new-line and carriage returns. and since you've just altered line to be just the text without the line-feed, you can delete your line with line.readline().

Update:
to skip lines beginning with #

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    if line[0]=="#":
        continue
    tokens = line.split()
```

by "skip", I take it to mean that you want to ignore them.

also, for good form, you should have in your parseFile function the line:

```
def parseFile(fn):
    global data
    ...
```

Comment: okay. i'm trying to skip over the #. i just updated the code above^^^ to give more information. Does the line.strip() command still work?

Comment: There is no need to strip whitespace off the ends of lines before splitting. `' 1 2 4 '.split() == ['1', '2', '4']`.

Comment: @Terry you're correct, if you are splitting on spaces. I always make a habit of using strip regardless of what I split on(which is rarely spaces).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  the guy clearly is just starting out if he's asking about parsing text. one step at a time, know what I mean. you should tone it down a bit.

Comment: @user1269942 I perfectly understand the OP is a beginner, and that's the very exact reason why you should NOT present globals as "good form" but instead show him how to avoid them. It's easier to learn proper practices right from the start than to learn bad habits then try to unlearn them.